# Unwanted top padding on Swift TabView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue which I cannot resolve. I have a TabView inside NavigationView with two tabs. Both tabs are constructed in the same way SearchBar + List, only difference is content, but issue appears even if I try to display the same content on both.

Issue is that on first tab there is extra padding between search bar and list, it does not appear on second tab. If I switch order in code issue is the same padding only on first tab (old second tab).

Important remark, it only happens with `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` with `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` there is no extra padding, but then I cannot expand and colapse categories.

[image: extra padding]
[image: no padding]

Code:

```
    var body: some View {   
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ProductList()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Produkty", systemImage: "bag.circle.fill")
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        self.title = "Produkty"
                    }
                RecipeList()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Przepisy", systemImage: "book.circle.fill")
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        self.title = "Przepisy"
                    }
            }
            .accentColor(.white)
            .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

Code for the `ProductList()`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductList: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    let categories: [String] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            
                List(){
                    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { cat in
                        Section(
                            header: Text(cat)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        ){
                            ForEach(productData.filter{
                                searchText.isEmpty && $0.category.rawValue == cat ? true : $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) && $0.category.rawValue == cat
                            }) { product in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product)){
                                    ProductRow(
                                        product: product,
                                        color: colorRank(value: product.rank[0].rawValue)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .accentColor(.gray)
                        
                    }
                }
                .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }.background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground).ignoresSafeArea())  
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a little more information, it looks like your issue is in how you built the list views, can you post their code as well? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure:
`List(){
 ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { cat in
  Section(header: Text(cat)){
   ForEach(productData.filter{
    searchText.isEmpty && $0.category.rawValue == cat ? true : $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) && $0.category.rawValue == cat
   }) { product in
    NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product)){
     ProductRow(product: product)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: ok, so if I'm reading correctly, this appears to be your `ProductList()`, what about your `RecipeList()`?

Can you also show us where you post the `.listStyle()` code for each tab?

The more information we have, the easier it is to solve :P

cheers :)

Comment: and could you post these snippets in the question (by editing the question) rather than in the comments?.... easier to read :)

Comment: sorry, I just realised you only posted the product list, Can you give us the full view? (including the search bar?).... the whole `ProductList()` struct please :) thanks

Comment: @Andy updated, `ReceipeList()` is build exactly same way, if I change order in `TabView` then issue appears in ReceipeList and not ProductList, also if I add 3rd tab at the begining, both lists are displayed fine, so issue is only with first tab. I have also tested some hack to destroy and create list when program is already running, and after destroing and recreating, new list is alright, no extra padding.